# How call Method in UserControl from a different form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to refill GridView on a Usercontrol (DashboardCTR) by calling a method (Reload_Dash) in the Usercontrol from a different form (FrmOpenShop) without creating a new instance of the UserControl.

I achieved this same task when using form like this:

```
foreach(Form appForm in Application.OpenForms)
{
     if(appForm.Name=="formName")
     {
          (Application.OpenForms["formName"] as formName).MethodName;
     }
}
```

But for Usercontrol,  am not user of how to get this done, i was hoping I could get it by following the approach stated above  like this:

```
foreach(UserControl control in Application.OpenForms)
{
     if(control.Name=="DashboardCTR")
     {
          (Application.OpenForms["DashboardCTR"] as DashboardCTR).Reload_Dash;
     }
}
```

But this didn't work, some idea would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the UserControl placed on a form? What's wrong with `formInstance.UserControlName.MethodName()`? You just need to make sure that the UserControl access modifier is set to `internal` or `public`.

Comment: You're side stepping the proper way to accomplish this by using `Application.OpenForms`.  Don't use that.  Instead, pass a REFERENCE from one form to the other and use that.  An easy way is to simply call `Show()` but pass in "this" `Show(this)`.  Then the form that was shown can cast the `.Owner` property to the correct form type and use that...

Answer (score -1):

A component's/control's `Modifiers` property annoyingly defaults to `private` when created, or if not that case, try adding in these protection modifiers: `public` and `static`, public goes before static.

The `public modifier` makes the method available to the user if the constructor is used.

The `static modifier` forces the method available only if the type is mentioned without using a constructor. This allows you to force a reload/redraw on the `UserControl` grid view or whatever. Allowing you to refresh it **anytime you want**.

Comment: That is definitely not what static is for.  Just making things public and/or static is a recipe bad design and plenty of bugs.